# Angular2 and Bootstrap: How do I activate (submit) event as well as close modal on form submit?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a form placed in a bootstrap modal. When user submits the form, the `(submit)` event should fire `addArticle($event)` and the modal should close.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="" style="text-align: center" (submit)="addArticle($event)">

        <div class="modal-header">

        </div>

         <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="_title" name="_title" />
             .......
        </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Create Article</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I do:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Create Article</button>
```

It just closes the modal but doesn't fire the `(submit)` event the form which is the same as closing the modal window.

Comment: Did you try?
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form)">

Comment: I copied your html into my Angular2 project, but my `addArticle($event)` was triggered.

Comment: With `data-dismiss="modal"` in the `Create Article` button? In my case, it just cancels the modal!

Comment: Yes. I did not try with an actual modal though. Are you using a third party library to show and dismiss the modal?

Answer (score 1):

its not clear which kind of angular 2 forms you are using.

for template driven forms

```
<form #signupForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(signupForm)">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ngModel>

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ngModel>

  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

and component should be like this import { Component } from

```
'@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'signup-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/signup-form.component.html',
})
export class SignupForm {
  registerUser(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
    // {email: '...', password: '...'}
    // ...
  }
}
```

i have used modal in one of my forms but in reactive forms. this is what you should do for closing popup and call submit function both at the same time

```
 <div class="modal-body">
      <form [formGroup]="addForm" class="box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" formControlName="username"  />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" formControlName="email"  />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="password"  />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password2" formControlName="password2"  />
            <div class='error' *ngIf="addForm.controls.password2.touched">
            <div class="alert-danger errormessageadduser" *ngIf="addForm.hasError('mismatchedPasswords')">
                Passwords do not match
                </div>
             </div>
             <br/>
            <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="addUser()" class="btn btn-primary"> Add User </button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

i hope this will help :)

Answer (score -5):

Its been long since I did AngularJS but I am guessing what you are trying to achieve is update your DOM instantly on submitting, so here is my suggestion, why don't you use ajax instead of raw submitting and make the ajax not async and update only if the submit is successful. Here is how you can do that:

```js
$('.form-class/id').submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax('url-here', {
    async: false,
    data: $('.your-form').serialize(), //also encode to json, works fine
    success: function() {
      //message for success
      $('.modal-class/id').modal('hide');
      addArtical(e);
    },
    error: function() {
      //message for error
    }
  });
  
  return false;
});
```

Something like that will sort you out
P.S. I haven't debugged this code and I hope this will help.